# I am getting:- Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: TOO_MANY_REQUESTS

Tags: java, sdk, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

```java
AuthenticationDetailsProvider provider = SimpleAuthenticationDetailsProvider.builder()
        .tenantId(oci_tenant_id)
        .userId(oci_user_id)
        .region(Region.AF_JOHANNESBURG_1)
        .fingerprint(oci_finger_print)
        .privateKeySupplier((Supplier) privateKeySupplier)
        .build();

ObjectStorage ociClient = new ObjectStorageClient(provider);
```

From the above I get the below exception when creating:

```java
ObjectStorage ociClient = new ObjectStorageClient(provider);
```

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang_.NoSuchFieldError Create breakpoints: TOO_MANY_REQUESTS
    at com.oracle.bmc.circuitbreaker.CircuitBreakerConfiguration.(CircuitBreakerConfiguration.java:44)
    at com.oracle.bmc.util.CircuitBreakerUtils.(CircuitBreakerUtils.java:35)
    at com.oracle.bmc.objectstorage.ObjectStorageClient.(ObjectStorageClient.java:317)
    at com.oracle.bmc.objectstorage.ObjectStorageClient.(ObjectStorageClient.java:224)
    at com.oracle.bmc.objectstorage.ObjectStorageClient.(ObjectStorageClient.java:187)
    at com.oracle.bmc.objectstorage.ObjectStorageClient.(ObjectStorageClient.java:152)
    at com.oracle.bmc.objectstorage.ObjectStorageClient.(ObjectStorageClient.java:124)
    at com.oracle.bmc.objectstorage.ObjectStorageClient.(ObjectStorageClient.java:99)
    at com.oracle.bmc.objectstorage.ObjectStorageClient.(ObjectStorageClient.java:76)
    at com.oracle.bmc.objectstorage.ObjectStorageClient.(ObjectStorageClient.java:62)
    at com.oracle.bmc.objectstorage.ObjectStorageClient.(ObjectStorageClient.java:51)
    at com.vodacom.oci.services.OCI_GenericUtility.getObjectClient(OCI_GenericUtility.java:137)
    at com.vodacom.oci.services.OCI_GenericUtility.main(OCI_GenericUtility.java:47)
```

Comment: Look for the field TOO_MANY_REQUESTS or provide more code, please

Comment: Hi, Thanks for feedback, above is the complete code for creating an objectStorageclient object. The field "TOO_MANY_REQUESTS", comes from com.oracle.bmc.circuitbreaker.CircuitBreakerConfiguration. The circuit Breaker is invoked by ObjectStoargeClient , Not sure why and how to resolve the issue

Comment: @M-zetMzamo did any of the provided solution works, I am blocked by this issue. but not able to resolve this from quite a some time.

Comment: @A.Sheroy, I had to figure it out by removing aws dependencies one by one, till I found the real culprit. Below was the dependency in pom.xml, that caused conflict. <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>com.emc.vipr</groupId>
            <artifactId>s3-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.3</version>
        </dependency>-->

Comment: Hi @M-zetMzamo I dont have any aws jars in my classpath but I am still facing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please share the output of `mvn dependency:tree` from the root directory of your project? It seems the dependency `jakarta.ws.rs:jakarta.ws.rs-api` is not pointing to the right version (`2.1.6`) or is being overridden by `javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api`. To resolve this, only `jakarta.ws.rs:jakarta.ws.rs-api` version `2.1.6` should be included in your project.

Comment: +- com.oracle.oci.sdk:oci-java-sdk:pom:2.24.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.3.2:compile
**[INFO] |  +- jakarta.ws.rs:jakarta.ws.rs-api:jar:2.1.6:compile**
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.33:compile
[INFO] +- com.oracle.oci.sdk:oci-java-sdk-core:jar:2.23.0:compile

Answer (score 0):

I removed *aws-java-sdk** dependencies from pom.xml, and my code worked. Looks like there is a conflict between *oci-java-sdk* and *aws-java-sdk* dependencies. The below dependencies were removed and the exception disappeared

```
<!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.908</version>
    </dependency>-->

<!--<dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.908</version>
    </dependency>-->
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error, reproducable with only two maven dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle.oci.sdk</groupId>
      <artifactId>oci-hdfs-connector</artifactId>
      <version>3.3.1.0.3.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

There is a old jar that is conflicting with jakarta, I found this one having the same classes:

```
javax.ws.rs:jsr311-api:jar:1.1.1:compile
```

Once it is excluded, error is gone
Simple way to exclude it, add direct dependency to it's parent, jersey-core, and exclude from it:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.19</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, in a project depending on both AWS and Oracle SDKs, the conflict is resolved by adding this dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

The OCI SDK depends on 'rs-api' >= 2.1 because it includes a constant `Response.Status.TOO_MANY_REQUESTS` which has `@since 2.1` in its Javadoc documentation.